# How can we call Availity API

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrequest

Currently, I am trying to call Availity API through JavaScript. Here is the cURL call:

```
curl -i -H "x-api-key: $API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https: //api.availity.com/demo/v1/institutional-claims -d {
"requestTypeCode": "PRE_DETERMINATION",
"billingProvider": {
    "npi": "1234567893",
    "ein": "111222333",
    "payerAssignedProviderId": "XYZ321"
},
```

I am using my valid key but result is `HTTP 404` error.

I have tried with `jQuery.ajax` but it doesn't work. Also, I tried to make this call with C# WebRequest, but it doesn't work too.

Is this possible to call this API from jQuery/JavaScript or from C#?

```
var tempk = {
        "requestTypeCode": "PRE_DETERMINATION",
        "billingProvider": {
            "npi": "1234567893",
            "ein": "111222333",
            "payerAssignedProviderId": "XYZ321"
        },
        "patient": {
            "relationshipCode": "01",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "stateCode": "FL",
            "birthDate": "1980-02-12",
            "genderCode": "M"
        },
        "payer": {
            "id": "BCBSF"
        },
        "submitter": {
            "id": "123456789",
            "lastName": "SUBMITTER"
        },
        "subscriber": {
            "memberId": "JDH001",
            "groupName": "ASDF 1-2",
            "groupNumber": "12312412"
        },
        "claimInformation": {
            "placeOfServiceCode": "11",
            "diagnoses": [
              {
                  "qualifierCode": "ABK",
                  "code": "J3089"
              }
            ],
            "serviceLines": [
              {
                  "procedureCode": "92523",
                  "quantity": "100",
                  "amount": "250",
                  "fromDate": "2016-05-10"
              }
            ]
        }
    };

       $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.availity.com/demo/v1/professional-claims',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        data:tempk,
        //"x-api-key: $API_KEY"
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            // Success callback
            alert(jsonData);
        },
        error: function () {
            //any error to be handled
        }
    });
```

Comment: it'll be possible from AJAX if it returns CORS headers - as you are getting 404, then you got little chance to know if it returns CORS headers

Comment: thank you. can you have some exmple, how to set key in header? and cors ,means corssdomain?thank you.

Comment: you want someone to write the javascript code for you? before you've even answered the simplest question ... i.e. "does that server send CORS headers" ... if it doesn't, your request is dead in the water, if it does, show **how** you `tried with jQuery.ajax`

Comment: no not full javascript/jquery code, just how to passed header of key due ,if that is possible then it is easy for me to integrate? I have tried with various ways.

Comment: `I have tried with various ways` - show them

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - look at **headers** under settings ... basically add `headers: {"header-name": "header value"}` to the settings object in the request

Comment: @jaromanda - I Have posted here where I have been tried and, can you review this and let me what can I do?

Comment: what is the problem? do you get errors in the developer tools console? if so, what are the errors? CORS errors? like I said 16 hours ago in the first comment?

Comment: thanks I have done with cors true

Comment: Can anyone help me with using avaiity  demo API